# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Connection reset) tomcat oracle

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jndi

I am trying to connect to a remote oracle database using JNDI connection via Tomcat. I'm using tomcat 8.0.41 and Oracle  12.1.0.2. I am using ojdbc7.jar for oracle driver. I tried ojdbc6.jar too. I keep getting this error message "Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Connection reset)  tomcat oracle" cause: "java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset". Could anyone help me with this? I spent nearly 3 days trying to figure this one out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by using ojdbc8.jar instead of ojdbc7.jar.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue and it got resolved when upgrading to  ojdbc8 jar

Comment: That is the same content as the existing answer's. If you do not have anything to add, please refrain from adding answers that already exist.